# ggplot2 legend color gradient adjustment

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

In the following code, I would like to change aspects of the legend so that the colour gradient of "log10_p_value" is represented in "plot_size".

[image]

So the the white bubbles representing "plot_size" also represent the colours of "log10_size"

The data can be loaded here:

```
one.data <-
  structure(list(plot_X = c(5.902, 1.184, 5.354, -3.513, 2.183, 
                            2.217, -4.548, 6.466, -7.38, -6.19,
                            -6.374, 2.294, -3.653),
                 plot_Y = c(3.903, 7.13, -3.64, -5.64, 1.534, -4.031,
                            5.709, 0.066, 0.531, -3.234, 2.502, 6.686, 6.26),
                 plot_size = c(7.284, 5.413, 7.612, 4.725,5.633, 5.232,
                               4.547, 6.474, 5.567, 6.277, 6.874, 5.277, 4.394),
                 log10_p_value = c(-2.5229, -2.1549, -1.4949, -3, -1.5376,
                                   -1.3565, -2.5229, -1.5229, -1.4949, -2.1549,
                                   -1.3665, -2.1549, -1.3565)),
            row.names = c(NA, 13L),
            class = "data.frame",
            .Names = c("plot_X", "plot_Y", "plot_size", "log10_p_value"))
```

The code to generate the plot is:

```
p1 <-
  ggplot(one.data
         , aes( plot_X
                , plot_Y
                , fill = log10_p_value
                , size = plot_size)) +
  geom_point(
    alpha = 0.6
    , shape = 21) +
  scale_size( range=c(0, 30)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn( colours = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red")) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = range(one.data$plot_X) + diff(range(one.data$plot_X))*c(-0.1, 0.1)
                  , ylim = range(one.data$plot_Y) + diff(range(one.data$plot_Y))*c(-0.1, 0.1))


p1
```

Comment: Color and shape are independent aesthetics, and one is discrete and one is continuous. What exactly do you want the output to be? It's not clear to me what you think the correct thing would be.

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: Thank you Mark, you have been very helpful. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to change the empty fill in the `plot_size` legend with a color from the color scale?

If so, this will work:

```
p1 + guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "orange", alpha = 0.6)))
```

to generate this

[image]

This is just over riding the default aesthetic for that legend (which is generally a "safe" value to avoid confusion with other aesthetics).

You could have each of them be a differnt color, but that is a really, really bad idea since the color does not correspond to the plot sizes you want:

```
p1 + guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("blue", "green", "red"), alpha = 0.6)))
```